# For any given non-null game, is there always a finite amount of Nash equilibria?

Tags: game-theory

Let's say I'm given a matrix ixj with n games, is there a finite amount of Nash equilibria for those games?

Comment: With n games? What does that mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking pure strategies Nash equilibria, then yes. Otherwise, you could have infinitely many mixed strategies Nash equilibria. Take a matrix in which all cells have the payoff vector $(1,1)$. So any convex combination of pure strategies is a Nash equilibrium.